how to get a gas estimate with web3.py
I've been trying all day to get a gas estimate for a transaction with web3.py.
This is the relevant part of the code I believe:
    # Estimate gas
    gas_estimate = self.hash_store_contract.functions.storeHash(hash_value).estimate_gas({
        'from': self.from_address,
        'nonce': nonce,
        'maxFeePerGas': self.web3.to_wei('2', 'gwei'),
        'maxPriorityFeePerGas': self.web3.to_wei('1', 'gwei')
    })

is this the standard way to estimate the gas for a transaction? How should I set the amount correctly in before sending the transaction. I haven't found a canonical answer to this. Also the documentation writes that we should use the parameters "maxFeePerGas" and "maxPriorityFeePerGas" but its not clear what they mean.
